# Cannot read all emails in mailbox with go-imap v1?

Tags: go, email, go-imap

I'm trying to fetch all emails from a certain sender with [go-imap v1](https://github.com/emersion/go-imap/tree/v1)

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/emersion/go-imap"
    "github.com/emersion/go-imap/client"
    "github.com/emersion/go-message/mail"
)

func main() {
    ccc, err := client.DialTLS("imappro.zoho.com:993", nil)

    if err := ccc.Login("xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx"); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to login: %v", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Succesfully logged in...\n")
    }

    mbox, err := ccc.Select("INBOX", false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    if mbox.Messages == 0 {
        log.Fatal("No message in mailbox")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Total message(s) in inbox: %d\n", mbox.Messages)
    }
    seqSet := new(imap.SeqSet)
    seqSet.AddNum(mbox.Messages)


    var section imap.BodySectionName
    items := []imap.FetchItem{section.FetchItem()}

    messages := make(chan *imap.Message, 1)
    go func() {
        if err := ccc.Fetch(seqSet, items, messages); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    for elem := range messages {
        if elem == nil {
            log.Fatal("Server didn't returned message")
        }

        r := elem.GetBody(&section)
        if r == nil {
            log.Fatal("Server didn't returned message body")
        }

        mr, err := mail.CreateReader(r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        header := mr.Header
        if date, err := header.Date(); err == nil {
            log.Println("Date:", date)
        }
        if from, err := header.AddressList("From"); err == nil {
            log.Println("From:", from)
        }
        if to, err := header.AddressList("To"); err == nil {
            log.Println("To:", to)
        }
        if subject, err := header.Subject(); err == nil {
            log.Println("Subject:", subject)
        }

    }

    if err := ccc.Logout(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to logout: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

There are 45 emails in the inbox, yet my code only print the very latest email, like this:

```
2023/09/11 17:22:33 Date: 2023-09-05 15:28:28 +0000 +0000
2023/09/11 17:22:33 From: ["xxxxx" <xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxx>]
2023/09/11 17:22:33 To: ["xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx" <xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx>]
2023/09/11 17:22:33 Subject: Yet another test
```

I don't see informations about the other 44 emails printed. What's wrong here?

Comment: `seqSet.AddNum(mbox.Messages)` mean cursor start from `mbox.Messages`, so replace it to `seqset.AddRange(0, mbox.Messages)` for get all mails.

Comment: Ah thanks @Trock. I got it work. For anyone looking for reference, this is my updated code: https://gist.github.com/anta40/d60d5c90c31907ceb0b04c9e4a721270